# Run ng serve Angular 4 using Angular CLI 6, it's possible?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project with Angular 4.

I update the Angular CLI:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 10.9.0
OS: win32 x64
```

So, how to run `ng serve` for my project with Angular 4?

The file `angular.json` doesn't exist for Angular 4.

Thanks advanced.

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
```

Comment: Either upgrade the project or downgrade the CLI version.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularCLI follows Angular releases closely. Especially for such switch like `angular.json` I doubt there is any valid way to handle this case.
If upgrading the project isn't possible, I would recommend downgrading the Angular CLI.

Please note that even https://update.angular.io/ doesn't recommend moving the projects across multiple major versions:

> Warning: We do not recommend moving across multiple major versions.

But if you choose to upgrade even one major version, there's a couple of things to do to handle the problem. In any case, this is a difficult topic. In case you're working with a legacy app with no easy way to upgrade the app, I would recommend choosing downgrading Angular CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any angular applications with AngularCLI 6 if it has lower version than your compiler(5.X.X or less), but you can have multiple versions of AngularCLI.

I'll recommend you to install the latest version of AngularCLI on your PC and specify another version in your `package.json`. On every start, you will receive a warning that tells "your version of AngularCLI is greater than the version in package.json. Your local version will be used instead of global.". This is just a message and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all answers.

So, in dev environment I can run using the commands `npm install` and `ng serve`.
After `npm install` the `Angular CLI: 6.1.1` change to `@angular/cli: 1.1.1`.

```
ngupgrade $] npm install
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer

> node-sass@4.9.3 install C:\dev\wks\wks-lab\ngUpgrade-without-preparation\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\alisson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.3\win32-x64-64_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall C:\dev\wks\wks-lab\ngUpgrade-without-preparation\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\dev\wks\wks-lab\ngUpgrade-without-preparation\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","ar
ch":"x64"})

added 1094 packages from 1162 contributors and audited 5834 packages in 381.117s
found 15 vulnerabilities (9 low, 6 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

ngupgrade $]ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / ? \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
node: 10.9.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.7
@angular/common: 4.4.7
@angular/compiler: 4.4.7
@angular/core: 4.4.7
@angular/forms: 4.4.7
@angular/http: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.7
@angular/router: 4.4.7
@angular/upgrade: 4.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7

ngupgrade $]ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: 6297789187cf54cae976
Time: 16458ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 195 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 10.7 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.5 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.59 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? Y

ngupgrade $]
```